How to put a SharePoint link to the current workbook in the email body in VBA?
We use an Excel sheet as a form. It passes to multiple people, so emails are sent to the next person in the workflow. Each form lives in a SharePoint library for tracking with the form being checked in/checked out.
I want to include a link to the workbook in the email body, so the next person can click the link and the workbook opens.
I have code that works, except it doesn't include the full path.
It links to the SharePoint Library but does not include the file name using ActiveWorkbook.FullName.
So it leads to a 404 not found page.
Sub submitform()

    'other code that doesn't matter
    
    ' Create a new instance of Outlook
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Create a new email
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    'fpath = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Drop Downs").Range("BC6") 'this is using a copy/paste of the link from the file -> share, this will work! It leads to the worksheet in the web version of Excel
    
    fpath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    Range("V92").Value = ActiveWorkbook.FullName 'debug point, this SHOWS the FULL file path just like im looking for in a cell. So why isnt it showing in the email body
    
    strbody = "<A href=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ">Access the setting here.</A>"
    
    ' Set the properties of the email
    With OutlookMail
        '.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .To = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Drop Downs").Range("AT17")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Drop Downs").Range("AT18")
        
        'the cell references are to add more body to the email body
        .HTMLBody = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Drop Downs").Range("AT19") & "<br>" & strbody & "<br>" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Drop Downs").Range("BD9")
        
        .Display ' Use .Send instead of .Display to send the email without displaying it
    End With

    ' Clean up
    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

When I change fpath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName to fpath = ActiveWorkbook.FullNameURLEncoded, it opens as read only by property of the URLEncoded, so this isn't suitable.
The link looks like this when I hover over it, with the ActiveWorkbook.FullName method: https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/stuff/library /MISSING THE REST

I'm surprised you find the Workbook is opened read-only when using ActiveWorkbook.FullNameURLEncoded as all this does (admittedly the documentation is rather vague) is convert any non-valid characters (eg space becomes %20) ... are you sure the Workbook is really read-only (note the docs for ActiveWorkbook.FullNameURLEncoded say "read only" but that means the ActiveWorkbook.FullNameURLEncoded property itself is read only ie you cannot set the property to a new value)

@JohnM when I test the link, it opens the workbook but it says "We can't check out the workbook. Click OK to open in read-only mode".                    When i hover over the link generated with URLEncoded, I can see the full address which is perfect, but can't check out the file. In the way I described above, the address stops right at the SP library and won't link to the file

I guess my point is that there is nothing about ActiveWorkbook.FullNameURLEncoded that means a file must be opened as read only ... it returns the same String as ActiveWorkbook.FullName other than converting some characters to URL-safe characters. I think your issue may the same as this SO Q&A.
